# Retrieving all gender values using checkbox in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an angular application that allows me to filter samples by gender. Filtering is done by checkboxes. Basically, users check male, female or both to retrieve the samples. So far, I have accomplished to provide male or female based on the checkbox selection. If there is no checkbox selected then I return all genders. Also, if they select male or female checkbox, I also return the correct list of samples. Now the problem is that if users check all checkboxes, they expect all genders obviously. But I return nothing. Because I have gender as an array and if users select all genders it becomes `gender = ['male', 'female']`. The server looks for gender as `malefemale`. Therefore it returns nothing. How can I retrieve all genders if they select all genders?

Here is my HTML template:

```
<label for="gender"><strong>Gender: </strong></label>
     <div *ngFor="let f of genderList" class="checkbox">
          <label for="gender{{ f.value }}">
          <input type="checkbox" id="gender{{ f.value }}" (change)="onGenderToggle(f.value, $event)"> {{ f.display }}
     </label>
</div>
```

In my component, I have `sampleParams` defined as `sampleParams: any = { gender: []};` and `genderList` as `genderList = [{value : 'male', display: 'Males'}, {value: 'female', display: 'Females'}];`

And I control checkboxes at `onGenderToggle` function as below:

```
onGenderToggle(genderValue, $event) {
  if ($event.target.checked) {
    this.sampleParams.gender.push(genderValue);
  } else {
    const index = this.sampleParams.gender.indexOf(genderValue);
    this.sampleParams.gender.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Please note that I didn't provide service codes since I have list loaded successfully.
I tried to use dropdown and radiobox already. But these provide either male or female list of samples. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is little explanation on how you filter your data later on. but a simple solution would be in pseudo code....

if length of array = 2, then if element in db or list is equal to male OR element in list is equal to female return element.

Also it can be also just a problem of how you send the data or how it is treated, without additional info its difficult to say

Answer (score 0):

If your backend expects `malefemale`, the very simplest solution is just to check the length of the array, if it's 2, then both are checked...

So something like...

```
if (this.sampleParams.gender.length === 2) {
  const param = 'malefemale';
}
this.myService.fetchData(param).subscribe(....)
```